Has anybody success with PHP sqlsrv-connection on macOS Sonoma 14.6.1 with XAMPP 8.1.17?
I could install und use the sqlsrv and sqlsrv_pdo driver packages from Microsoft on Windows and Ubuntu24.04 but for MacOS always failed to load connect to the driver at runtime!!!! Not even any php screen error logging works as in the php-file enabled:
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$serverName = '1nnnnn'; // Or your server name
$connectionOptions = array(
    "Database" => 'Ifffffff', // Your database name
    'Uid' => 'ddddddd',
    'PWD' => 'passwoooord',
);
//echo "???"; // when this two commented lines are uncommented the site shows ???
//exit(); // when this two commented lines are uncommented the site shows ???
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionOptions);
if ($conn === false) {
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
echo "Connection successful!";
?>

XAMPP/Apache works fine for any php but when calling sqlsrv_connect the browser shows 'unable to open' and error in php_error_log-file is:
dyld[8251]: Assertion failed: (this->magic == kMagic), function loadAddress, file Loader.cpp, line 163.
The driver files are in correct location:
@MacBook-Pro-von-Ha---en no-debug-non-zts-20210902 % ls
opcache.so  pdo_dblib.so    pdo_sqlsrv.so   pgsql.so    sqlsrv.so


In the php.ini file extensions are loaded:
extension=sqlsrv.so
extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so

Correct access given:
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 root  admin   26720  6 Apr  2023 pdo_dblib.so
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 root  admin  333216 11 Sep 15:42 pdo_sqlsrv.so
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 root  admin  117680  6 Apr  2023 pgsql.so
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 root  admin  336880 11 Sep 17:14 sqlsrv.so


ODBC installed
g@MacBook-Pro-von-Ha---en no-debug-non-zts-20210902 % odbcinst -j

unixODBC 2.3.12
DRIVERS............: /usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /usr/local/etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /usr/local/etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /Users/hjbeling/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8



$serverName = "1nnnnn“; is a syntax error. the “ needs to be changed to ". You have the same problem in a few other places in the code as well - check it carefully. Make sure you use a proper IDE to write your code, and not any kind of rich-text editor. Anyway that's why error_reporting doesn't have any effect - the code isn't executed due to the syntax error, so the command never runs. Far better to enable error reporting (and/or logging errors to a file) in the php.ini settings, rather than in the code. That way you'll see compile-time errors as well.

Thank you for your reply ADyson. But the conversion was made by an editor that I used to change the credentials. And that would be an error that would have been shown by error reporting and not cause Loader error. And I have changed all " signs with ' signs and the error remains the same.

What editor was that? Don't use it again. And no, a syntax error would not show up as a result of the error_reporting() function, for the reasons I already explained.

Anyway if you fixed that, please [edit] your question to show your latest code, so we can verify what you are now trying to execute

And Assertion failed: (this->magic == kMagic), function loadAddress, file Loader.cpp definitely isn't a PHP error. For a start, .cpp suggests a C++ code file. It could possibly be an Apache issue...make sure you've got the latest updates of all the components, including Apache, PHP, the sqlsrv drivers, and MacOS itself. Unfortunately it's an unusual error and information online about it is not very plentiful

when I run on the cli: `g@MacBook-Pro-von-Ha....en test % php sql.php
Connection successful!

But in browser still cannot be displayed

Include that information in your question, it might be useful. And what exactly is the full error message you see in the browser when you try to load the page?

Problem solved!
I finally installed php, the sqlsrv drivers and apache the way microsoft recommended:
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=sql-server-ver16#installing-on-macos
It was tricky at the end of step 4:
echo "LoadModule php7_module /usr/local/opt/php@8.1/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so" >> /usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf
    (echo "<FilesMatch .php$>"; echo "SetHandler application/x-httpd-php"; echo "</FilesMatch>";) >> /usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf

libphp7.so is wrong and the correct lines in httpd.conf were:
LoadModule php_module /usr/local/opt/php@8.1/lib/httpd/modules/libphp.so
<FilesMatch .php$>
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>

It was helpful to note ALL the outputs of the brew processes to know where the directories are and how to start and other things
